# Answers/Questions proportion

Tags: discussion

I am a member of this community for the last 6 months and I have noticed that there users that answer a lot and question a little (usually the established users) and others that question a lot and answer a little (the new comers).

So a ratio like `(PointsFromAnswers+1)/(PointsFromQuestions+1)` is lower bounded in SE in any way?

Just curiosity here :-)

For example someone could ask 400 questions but not give any answer in any other's question. So I am wondering what will happen if thousands of users in the future only ask questions. There should be a motivation for them to join also the answering process.

So my question is : Is there a threshold where the user get's a message to offer back to the community ?

Maybe my question is naive due to my experience here.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no threashold.

From my perspective answering questions is more rewarding. It doesn't depend on the fact that an upvote for an answer is equivalent to `+10` points of reputation while an upvote for a question yields only `+5` rep. points. I asked on *M.SE* only 3 questions because: 
 I find  asking interesting questions more laborious since I have to check many ways to exclude possible simple solutions to given problem,  sometimes it may appear that I couldn't get a good answer just because of not quite precisely formulated problem (I have to say that my questions are precise).
I guess answering questions is instructive to most of the high rep. users since they learn much trying to answer real questions.
To sum up I don't see there is a problem- too many questions vs. too few answers.
I find one problem that some questions repeat many times though in different formulations. 
Another problem is rather low quality of a high fraction of all questions.

Comment: Not to mention that after you become reasonably experienced in _Mathematica_, the only questions you can ask have a high chance to be about bugs, which usually cannot be answered by the community.

Comment: This is another interesting dilemma. Very experienced Moderators (I mean with 10k+) can put questions that really corresponds to spreading their programming experience in Mathematica. In this way an increase to the average knowledge eventually will happen. And maybe then more real questions will arise...

Comment: @IstvánZachar I should say that I have many questions concerning Mathematica programming, however it appears that after some searching I could answer my own questions. There is another class of questions which most likely I will not ask since I don't expect to get answers (they concern rather difficult mathematical problems). Here is a related thread: [Questions on using Mathematica in mathematical research](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129/questions-on-using-mathematica-in-mathematical-research).

Comment: On the other hand there are very experienced `Mathematica` programmers who ask many questions, e.g. Mr.Wizard, Szabolcs, etc.

Comment: Many of the questions I posted here were more or less an excuse to post interesting tidbits I had been working on. A couple of Qs were related to suspected bugs for which I sought confirmation.